# Davenport on tomcat

Tags: tomcat, webdav, ubuntu-10.04

I am trying to make some samba shares available via Webdav and there are many references to davenport (http://davenport.sourceforge.net/), however there is not much information about how to set this up with Tomcat (I don't know tomcat very well.) Does anyone know of a Howto or at least some basic instructions on how to configure Davenport with Tomcat?

Comment: Wrong stack, sorry. But if you got anything please post!

Answer (score 1):

Just had to do the same thing myself.  First, make sure tomcat6 is installed, then move the contents of the webapp/root folder to a folder for davenport.  I moved it to /usr/share/davenport.  Finally, create an xml file in /etc/tomcat6/Catalina/localhost that points to your folder.  Mine was like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
(the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
-->
<Context path="/host-manager" 
    docBase="/usr/share/davenport/" 
    antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" />
```

Whatever you name the .xml will be the path to the app.  So davenport.xml means you have to access it with http://ipaddress:8080/davenport

Restart tomcat6 and you should be able to access the app.

Hope that helps!